# Apply different CSS style localy in a webpage that contain multiple webpages

Tags: html, css

I'm using difference CSS (almost 10) and I have a web page that contains multiple webpages and each page with thier specified CSS but the result gives me Headache all the CSS mixed with each other, I tried to declare the CSS separately in the head of each pages like this:

```
<head>
    <title>My web page</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
```

but it doesn't work, any idea how to make a CSS local declaration so I can use it in a specific elements without recreate all the HTML by `class=" "` . I want to apply different CSS style in a webpage that contain multiple webpages any declaration to do that?

Comment: why on earth does your page have multiple web pages?

Comment: cause i have a popup script who need a specific head parameters

Comment: @Prisoner I think that he is saying that he got one website with multiple pages

Comment: @Azrael no he's right :)

Comment: But why adding a different CSS file to each page (common sense aside) doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you come up with a common CSS for all the pages (though you might not even need it) - sets of rules that all of them would use, like defining body styles, reset rules for some elements, etc... Then, in every page you would include that CSS first, and then the webpage-specific CSS after. Like this:

Page 1

```
<head>
    <title>My web page 1</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/page1.css"/>
</head>
```

Page 2

```
<head>
    <title>My web page 2</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/page2.css"/>
</head>
```

etc...

Comment: mmm thanks but i did it , the probleme that i have multiple pages in one page.